# Subscribing to Observable in service from component

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-services, angular2-observables

I have searched for quite some time to understand how to subscribe to an array whose values are constantly updated.

I need to understand how to setup my Angular 2+ service observable correctly and subscribe to it in my component correctly. Please assume all other parts of the code works correctly.

```
@Injectable()
export class AutocompleteService {

    searchTerm: string;
    results = [];
    observe$ = Observable.from(this.results);

    searchTest(term){
        this.searchTerm = term.toLowerCase();

        if(this.searchTerm.length > 2){
            this.recruiters.forEach(function(el){
                if(el.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) != -1) {
                    this.results.push(el);
                }   
            });    

        }
    }

    getCurrentResults():Observable<Object> {
        return this.observe$;
    }
```

Everything in the service works as expected. If I log the `term` I get user input from my component. Or the `results` array after matching search results are pushed onto it.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'autocomplete',
    templateUrl: './autocomplete.component.html',
    providers: [AutocompleteService]
})
export class AutocompleteComponent implements OnInit{
    constructor(private autocompleteService: AutocompleteService){}

    value: string = '';
    searchControl = new FormControl();

    // fired when input happens
    getResults(event){
        this.autocompleteService.searchTest(event.target.value);

        this.autocompleteService.getCurrentResults().subscribe(
            value => console.log(value)
        );

    }
```

I have setup the observable pattern to the best of my ability but I'm not getting anything out of the .subscribe in getResults

Comment: what is that you want to know and where is your problem , its unclear with this line - 
I need to understand how to setup my Angular 2+ service observable correctly and subscribe to it in my component correctly.

Comment: Thanks @RahulSingh I have setup the observable pattern as I have learned to the best of my ability but I'm not getting anything out of the .subscribe in getResults

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I addition to what [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) and [echonax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5706293/echonax) said:

you can use Subject :

```
@Injectable()
export class AutocompleteService {

    searchTerm: string;
    results = [];
    subject = new Subject();

    searchTest(term){
        this.searchTerm = term.toLowerCase();

        if(this.searchTerm.length > 2){
            this.recruiters.forEach(el =>{
                if(el.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) != -1) {
                    this.subject.next(el);
                }   
            });    

        }
    }

    getCurrentResults():Subject<Object> {
        return this.subject;
    }
```

}

and subscribe to `getCurrentResults()` the same way you did.

you demo : [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2Umou05R0WCvlaxvByWE)

Answer (score 5):

There are many errors in your code

1. There isn't a `this.recruiters` field in your service
2. `this.results.push(el);` won't push anything to results because you are using `forEach(function(el){` it should've been `forEach((el)=>` so that your `this` inside the scope would refer to your service.

Example plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/5L0dE7ZNgpJSK4AbK0oM?p=preview